# Getting date from dialog fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

There seem to be many question related to this topic. When i read most of them i had one problem. Usually people try to make a fragment and then spawn a dialog fragment from there. So the dialog fragment is inside the fragment.

In my case i have created a button that opens a dialogfragment on the toolbar. Then i open my main fragment from the navigation bar. So the dialogfragment and my main fragment are getting called through the same main activity, just in different places. I cannot call the dialog fragment from inside the fragment since its getting called when the menu options are selected.

I tried to create a an interface with and a listener when im trying to
newFragment.setTargetFragment(somethinghere, 1); i have no idea on what i should be putting on the somethinghere field. getactivity,mealsworkoutfragment and .this are wrong)

I also tried to make my fragment extends Dialogfragment instead but this spawns my fragment everytime i press the button, which seems like an awful way to do this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.date_picker) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.mealworkoutTab) {
            iconShow = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            FragmentTransaction mealsworkoutsFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mealsworkoutsFrag.replace(R.id.flMain,new MealsWorkoutsFragment());
            mealsworkoutsFrag.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.userinfoTab) {
            iconShow = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            FragmentTransaction userInfoFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            userInfoFrag.replace(R.id.flMain,new UserInfoFragment());
            userInfoFrag.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.logoutTab) {
            auth.signOut();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Im guessing that a simple solution must exist since this looks a bit trivial (get sth from a dialogfragment to a fragment)

Comment: Simply send a local broadcast when a date is selected and listen to it in the activity

Comment: Since i already have frag extends Fragment can i also extend BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion would be to use library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) in such cases to convey and listen listen to "events" and pass data. So in your case, when the user selects the date, an 'event' with the selected date payload is posted. This event is then caught inside your Fragment (because you make your Fragment subscribe to this specific event) and then you can handle the payload (selected date) as you like.

If the above sounds too tough to follow or picture, please visit the link above. It has example codes. This library is extremely simple to implement and quite helpful in such scenarios.

Comment: That seems more complicated than i imagined. That is a 3rd party library, right? I guess google hasnt made anything like this yet. Though ive checked some videos and it seems like this will do the job.